# Which of the following pairs of vector spaces are isomorphic? Justify.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Which of the following pairs of vector spaces are isomorphic? Justify.

a).$F^3$ and $P_3(F)$

b). $F^4$ and $P_3(F)$.

c). $M_{2*2}(R)$ and $P_3(R)$

d) $V={A \in M_{2*2}(R): tr(A)=0}$ and $R^4$

Is this theorem enough to answer all of these?

> Let V and W be finite-dimensional vector spaces (over the same field). Then V is isomorphic to W if and only if $dim(V) = dim(W)$.

From this theorem, I would say

a). no

b). yes

c). No

d). no.

Comment: Assuming $P_n(\mathbb F)$ denotes the vector space of polynomials of degree $≤n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb F$....what dimension do you suppose $P_n(\mathbb F)$ has?

Comment: fixed, is it right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, $(a)$ is false and $(b)$, $(c)$ are true. Recall that, $P_n(F)$ has dimension $n+1$, since $$\underbrace{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n}_{n+1}$$ is a basis for that vector space.